# How to load image in ckeditor by relative path

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I am using CKeditor to preview an HTML template at some location outside the web application, say C:/editor/template and the images used by this html template at C:/editor/template/images.

when I open this template in ckeditor, the html template loads but without images. However if I open this html directly in browser I can see those images. How can we load these images in CKeditor?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it is related to the [Advanced content filtering](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_acf.html).
Look for what attributes are in your img tag and explicitly allow those.
Or allow all attributes in the img tag with this config:

```
var myCkeditor = CKEDITOR.replace(editorId, {
extraAllowedContent: 'img(*){*}[*];'
}
```